# EFCore roll back migration error: column of invalid type to be used as key column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to rollback a migration on a database that already has the migration applied.

This is the error I get:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE [EventStaffRequest] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_EventStaffRequest] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Column 'Id' in table 'EventStaffRequest' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

ClientConnectionId:29574816-2b1a-4490-a216-a54cd7a2d33b
Error Number:1919,State:1,Class:16
Column 'Id' in table 'EventStaffRequest' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

This is the migration I'm trying to rollback:

```
public partial class AddedCompositeKeyToEventStaffRequest : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_EventStaffRequest",
            table: "EventStaffRequest");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_EventStaffRequest_EventId",
            table: "EventStaffRequest");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Id",
            table: "EventStaffRequest");

        migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_EventStaffRequest",
            table: "EventStaffRequest",
            columns: new[] { "EventId", "QualityTypeId" });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_EventStaffRequest",
            table: "EventStaffRequest");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "EventStaffRequest",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "");

        migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_EventStaffRequest",
            table: "EventStaffRequest",
            column: "Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_EventStaffRequest_EventId",
            table: "EventStaffRequest",
            column: "EventId");
    }
}
```

If it is relevant, this is my model code:

```
public class EventStaffRequest
{
    [Required]
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string QualityTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual QualityType QualityType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AmountRequired { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int MinimumRating { get; set; }
}
```

This migration was created because I decided I needed to change the primary key to be a composite key. I have applied a composite primary key like so in my DbContext (this is what you see in the migration's `Up()` I guess):

```
builder.Entity<EventStaffRequest>()
    .HasKey(esr => new { esr.EventId, esr.QualityTypeId });
```

Why is my rollback not succeeding? I don't understand why `string` is not an appropriate type for key index (I use GUIDs as keys).

Comment: Can you have a default value on a non-nullable PK? Is there data in your table? Unless the table is empty, you cannot create a PK on a column with all equal default values...

Comment: Most likely you need to add `maxLength: some_value` to `AddColumn(...)` (string with unlimited length cannot be used as PK). But then you'll need also to populate the column with unique data, otherwise `AddPrimaryKey` will fail. In general, a migration like this which leads to data loss (by removing a column) is not reversible.

Comment: @oerlekens The EventStaffRequest table is empty, I have removed all records prior to rolling back the migration. I've tried setting  `defaultvalue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` in the migration but sadly that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, that solved it. I added `maxLength: 100` and now the migration could be rolled back just fine. Thanks! Data loss is not a problem for me, the project is still in development but I was struggling rolling back my database to switch to a different feature branch. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be an issue with migration system. The problem is not the `string` (of course it can be used for PK), but the `maxLength`. By default, the `string` columns have unlimited length, but PK require applying some limit.

Normally when you use `string` column as PK, even if you don't specify `maxLength`, EF automatically applies some limit (from what I see, at least for SqlServer it is `450`). Interestingly, doing the same what you did in reverse order generates similar migrations with `Up` and `Down` content swapped, and the exact same code for `AddColumn` works. But not when executed in `Down` method, so there must be a difference (hence a problem) in that path. You might consider posting it in EF Core issue tracker so they know (and eventually fix it).

Anyway, the solution is to explicitly add `maxLength` parameter to `AddColumn` call:

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
    name: "Id",
    table: "EventStaffRequest",
    maxLength: 450,
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: "");
```